# Named tuples existence in a hashset

Tags: python

```
In [1]: x = set()
In [2]: pos = collections.namedtuple('Position', ['x','y'])
In [4]: x.add(pos(1,1))
In [5]: x
Out[5]: {Position(x=1, y=1)}
In [6]: pos(1,1) in x
Out[6]: True
In [8]: pos(1,2) in x
Out[8]: False
```

I was not expecting Line 6 `pos(1,1) in x` to work. Since it does seem that pos(1,1) creates an object with a different object id every time.

```
In [9]: id(pos(1,1))
Out[9]: 140290954200696
In [10]: id(pos(1,1))
Out[10]: 140290954171016
```

How does the set `in` operator work on named tuples in this case? Does it check the contents of namedtuple?

Comment: I assume that `in` checks if any object `a` is equal to any member in `x` (the hashed element)

Answer (score 6):

`namedtuple` is not special. The element should be exactly equal(`__eq__`) and must have similar `hash` to pass the containment test.

```
>>> hash(pos(1, 1)) == hash(pos(1, 1))
True
>>> pos(1, 1) == pos(1, 1)
True
```

If you are interested, see the implementation [here<sup>Github</sup>](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9f33ede12710c454643c394421f52d209247272c/Objects/setobject.c#L363-L373). `set().__contains__(y)` first have to compute the `hash` value of `y`.

```
static int
set_contains_key(PySetObject *so, PyObject *key)
{
    Py_hash_t hash;

    if (!PyUnicode_CheckExact(key) ||
        (hash = _PyASCIIObject_CAST(key)->hash) == -1) {
        hash = PyObject_Hash(key);
        if (hash == -1)
            return -1;
    }
    return set_contains_entry(so, key, hash);
}
```

but computing `hash` alone does not says whether the elements are equal. For example:

```
>>> hash(-1)
-2
>>> hash(-2)
-2
```

Which means that if the hash values are equal then  [`__eq__` check is required to confirm if the elements are exactly equal](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/setobject.c#L88).

Please note that my answer is purely based on Cpython implementation.

Comment: Oh so the hash is computed based on its content than the object id? I see, that would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

A tuple of hashable objects is hashable, so it can be used as a member of a set and therefore pass the `in` check.
Since you are using numbers as tuple values, which are obviously hashable, there is no problem hashing the entire tuple.