Class as dictionary key not recognizing duplicates
I am wanting to use a class as a dictionary key and have implemented the __hash__ function and it appears to work. However, when I have a different instance of a class that has the same hash value, it is not recognized as being contained within the dictionary. MWE:
class foo:
    def __init__(self, name, i, j):
        self.name = name
        self.i = i
        self.j = j

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.name, self.i, self.j))


bar1 = foo('test', 1, 2)
bar2 = foo('test', 1, 2)

my_dict = {bar1: 'bar'}

print(bar1 in my_dict) # True
print(bar2 in my_dict) # False
print(hash(bar1) == hash(bar2)) # True

Can someone explain this behavior? I expected the hash value to also be used to determine whether an object is contained within the dictionary.
Running on Python 3.12.2 on Windows 10.

It must pass the == check and the hash check

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74472423/named-tuples-existence-in-a-hashset/74472472#74472472

Can you explain why you think this behavior was unexpected?

If hash alone were used to check the existence of a key, -1 and -2 would have been same :)(Try hash(-1) and hash(-2) in your python interpreter)

As spelled in the comments, for instances of a class to be able to work as dictionary keys or set members, it has to implement both __hash__ and the __eq__ methods.
Just do that, and it will work as you expect.
class foo:

    def __init__(self, name, i, j):
        self.name = name
        self.i = i
        self.j = j

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.name, self.i, self.j))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, type(self)):
            return False
        return self.name == other.name and self.i == other.i and self.j == other.j

